# How do I get split screen apps to both stay active

Tags: xiaomi, miui, multitasking, multi-window, focus

I am trying to run 2 apps in split screen with both staying active at the same time. Most results on google are saying this is not possible and they blame the app for it not working. Below is some detailed testing I have done.

This is an android issue/setting, not an app issue. The reason I know this is because I have 2 phones both using split screen. One can/will/does keep *both* apps active at the same time while one pauses whichever one is not in focus. The apps are identical across both phones.

- **Apps for testing:** Pokemon Go (Pogo) + Jurassic World Alive (JWA) (both AR games that use GPS and real time location constantly).
- **Phones for testing**: Moto X4 and Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus (I have previously tested on the Axon 7 and the Nexus 4-5-6, both behave the
  same as the Moto X4 currently does).
- **Android versions:** Redmi5 - Android 7.1.2 (MIUI 9.6.2.0) | Moto X4 - Android 8.1.0
- **One item of note:** On the Moto I had to enable developer mode and turn on 'Force activities to be resizable' before either app could be
  put into split screen. On the Redmi5 this was not needed as it was
  already enabled.
- **Test method:** Open Pogo normally. Use the 'intents' (app switch) button and at top click the section titled "split screen" (both
  phones have slightly diff wording here). Drag Pogo up there and it
  takes up the top half of the screen. In the bottom section, select
  previously running JWA (or start it from home screen) and it will
  take up the bottom section of the screen.
- **Wanted outcome (Redmi 5 Plus):** Top portion continues without pausing and bottom game loads and works without pausing. Both apps
  continue to run as if they were running in full screen and were
  active
- **Unwanted outcome (Moto X4/Axon7/Nexus(4|5|6):** Top app freezes
  or pauses when you load the bottom app. To unpause it, click on it,
  but this pauses the bottom app. Whichever app was last clicked on is
  active.

Since the apps I am using to test are identical across 3 of the phones I am testing (never tested JWA on the nexus phones) this cannot simply be an issue with the apps not supporting it. There has to be some setting that Xiaomi or MIUI enabled to allow this to work.

Another note, I am not trying to get *only* these 2 apps working, but these are 2 I would like to have working and made for good test apps due to how they run.

I realize my ask here may be unclear. *I want to know how to duplicate the functionality from the Redmi 5 Plus on my other devices (Moto X4, etc).*

**'Duplicate' edit:** I do not feel like the question listed as duplicate answers mine other than "you cant", but obviously MIUI or Xiaomi did. Also that answer seems to point to some side effects I should be experiencing on my Redmi that I am not (apps not pausing when minimized/unfocused).